# Multiline ellipsis in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there a way to achieve multiline ellipsis text in ionic 2. I have a card view and need to restrict maximum 2 lines to be showed inside it with vertical center alignment. I tried webkit css option but it is not working. I saw similar questions asked by others but couldn't figure out an answer for it.
Below is my html code

```
 <ion-content class="cards-bg light-gray">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-card *ngFor="let od of orderDetails” class="fade_logo">
            <ion-card-content> {{od.description}} </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

Here the order description is long text, I just need to show only 2 lines.

Comment: Put your code or image about what you want.

Comment: Updated my html code

Answer (score 2):

It depends on font size and line height but put this in your `.scss` file and also change the `height:` to get the best result.

```
ion-card-content {
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: It is just clipping the lines. The ellipsis 3 dot lines are not showing.